# Extracting numbers from column with string connected through repeated punctuation character

Tags: r, gsub

I have a column with values like this:

```
string.b.string.1.
string.b.string.2.
string.b.string.3.
string.b.string.10.
string.b.string.300.
```

and so on, with number from 0 to 300

I need to extract and remove the number from this column and put it in another column resulting in an output like this:

```
"Id"          "Variable"   
1             string.b.string
2             string.b.string
3             string.b.string
10            string.b.string
300           string.b.string
```

All my tries with gsub() or readr::parse_number() so far failed miserably as I just do not get the syntax of these gsub() functions. I failed usually, because the "." is repeating in the variable...

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::extract` :

```
tidyr::extract(df, V1, c('Variable', 'Id'), '(.*?)(\\d+)', convert = TRUE) 

#          Variable  Id
#1 string.b.string.   1
#2 string.b.string.   2
#3 string.b.string.   3
#4 string.b.string.  10
#5 string.b.string. 300
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("string.b.string.1.", "string.b.string.2.", 
"string.b.string.3.", "string.b.string.10.", "string.b.string.300."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to elaborate, what '(.*?)(\\d+)' exactly does?

Comment: The 1st column is everything until a number is encountered which is `(.*?)` part and the second column is the number i.e `(\\d+)`. .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcapture` from *base*.

```
strcapture("(.*)\\.(\\d+)", df$V1,
 data.frame(Variable=character(), Id=integer()))
#         Variable  Id
#1 string.b.string   1
#2 string.b.string   2
#3 string.b.string   3
#4 string.b.string  10
#5 string.b.string 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(.*)\\.(\\d+)\\.$", "\\1,\\2", df$V1), header = FALSE,
      col.names = c('Variable', 'Id'))
```

-output

```
#         Variable  Id
#1 string.b.string   1
#2 string.b.string   2
#3 string.b.string   3
#4 string.b.string  10
#5 string.b.string 300
```